# How does "incompatible site" IE mode works for edge? Are there any known example?

Tags: internet-explorer, microsoft-edge

Edge now as the default behavior of opening incompatible site in IE mode.
Are there any known example of such site or any way to make one?
What makes a website incompatible with edge/reload in IE mode?

Thank you,

Comment: May I know if you have got any chance to check my answer? I am glad to help if you have any other questions.

Answer (score 0):

> Edge now as the default behavior of opening incompatible site in IE mode.

I am a bit confused about this. Is the `incompatible site` you mentioned incompatible with Edge or incompatible with IE? As far as I know, if a site is not compatible with IE, it will be redirected to Edge by default. As described in this document: [Policies to configure redirection to Microsoft Edge](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/deployedge/edge-learnmore-neededge#policy-redirectsitesfrominternetexplorerredirectmode).

> What makes a website incompatible with edge/reload in IE mode?

Many modern websites have designs that are incompatible with Internet Explorer. For example, use ES6 syntax, special css styles, frameworks, etc. that are not supported by IE. When the site is not compatible with IE, it will be redirected to Edge and cannot be reloaded in IE mode.